# Kubernetes config map symlinks (..data/) : is there a way to avoid them?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I have noticed that when I create and mount a config map that contains some text files, the container will see those files as symlinks to `../data/myfile.txt` .

For example, if my config map is named tc-configs and contains 2 xml files named stripe1.xml and stripe2.xml, if I mount this config map to /configs in my container, I will have, in my container :

```
bash-4.4# ls -al /configs/
total 12
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root          4096 Jun  4 14:47 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jun  4 14:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jun  4 14:47 ..2018_06_04_14_47_03.291041453
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            31 Jun  4 14:47 ..data -> ..2018_06_04_14_47_03.291041453
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            18 Jun  4 14:47 stripe1.xml -> ..data/stripe1.xml
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            18 Jun  4 14:47 stripe2.xml -> ..data/stripe2.xml
```

I guess Kubernetes requires those symlinks and ../data and ..timestamp/ folders, but I know some applications that can fail to startup if they see non expected files or folders

Is there a way to tell Kubernetes not to generate all those symlinks and directly mount the files ?

Comment: I have the same problem with a Grafana container where I want to mount something into a plugins subfolder. This causes Grafana to not load the appropriate plugin with the error message `Could not scan dir \"/var/lib/grafana/plugins\" error: lstat ..2020_10_02_06_45_20.158884790: no such file or directory"`.
Unfortunately, the workaround with the `subPath` property is no solution for me as I need the automatic update feature of the configmap mount... I guess for the moment there is no other option for me than to restart the pod and not use any auto-update mechanism.

Answer (score 23):

I think this solution is satisfactory : specifying exact file path in mountPath, will get rid of the symlinks to `..data and  ..2018_06_04_19_31_41.860238952`

So if I apply such a manifest :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-lamp-site
spec:
    containers:
    - name: php
      image: php:7.0-apache
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/www/html/users.xml
        name: site-data
        subPath: users.xml
    volumes:
    - name: site-data
      configMap:
        name: users

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: users
data:
  users.xml: |
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
      <users>
      </users>
```

Apparently, I'm making use of [subpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) explicitly, and they're not part of the "auto update magic" from ConfigMaps, I won't see any more symlinks :

```
$ kubectl exec  my-lamp-site -c php -- ls -al /var/www/html
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  4 19:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     4096 Jun  4 17:58 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       73 Jun  4 19:18 users.xml
```

Be careful to not forget `subPath`, otherwise users.xml will be a directory !

Back to my initial manifest :

```
spec:
    containers:
    - name: php
      image: php:7.0-apache
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/www/html
        name: site-data
    volumes:
    - name: site-data
      configMap:
        name: users
```

I'll see those symlinks coming back :

```
$ kubectl exec  my-lamp-site -c php -- ls -al /var/www/html
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jun  4 19:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun  4 17:58 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  4 19:31 ..2018_06_04_19_31_41.860238952
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Jun  4 19:31 ..data -> ..2018_06_04_19_31_41.860238952
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Jun  4 19:31 users.xml -> ..data/users.xml
```

**Many thanks to [psycotica0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46842/psycotica0) on [K8s Canada slack](https://k8scanada.slack.com/) for putting me on the right track with [subpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) (they are quickly mentioned in [configmap documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume))**

Comment: But what if your configMap contains multiple files that should be included exactly as `users.xml`?

Comment: This solution will NOT work If configMap contains multiple files. I.e. the master changelog file which one explicitly mount as file with subPath will be defined as directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I don't know if you can tell Kubernetes not to generate those symlinks although I think that it is a native behaviour.

If having those files and links is an issue, a workaround that I can think of is to mount the configmap on one folder and copy the files over to another folder when you initialise the container:

```
  initContainers:
    - name: copy-config
      image: busybox
      command: ['sh', '-c', 'cp /configmap/* /configs']
      volumeMounts:
        - name: configmap
          mountPath: /configmap
        - name: config
          mountPath: /configs
```

But you would have to declare two volumes, one for the configMap (configmap) and one for the final directory (config):

```
  volumes:
    - name: config
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: configmap
      configMap:
        name: myconfigmap
```

Change the type of volume for the config volume as you please obviously.

Comment: thanks @iomv : that could be a workaround, true - although I wish there was a "cleaner" solution to do this !